# HTML basic authentification in URL

Tags: html, css, authentication

I host my own website at home (using wamp) that uses basic authentification. The authentification worked well and `username:password` in the url worked too. But since last week, when I load url with `username:password@url.com` it doesn't work and it seems that the css /js data won´t load. I tried this with a bootstrap example site and it worked. So I guess the problem is my website.

[Here is my website template](http://stack:123456@88.182.191.233:8090/stackoverflow/index2.html), as you can see the CSS doesn´t work except when reloaded.

I don't have this problem at the bootstrap example site [(Link)](http://stack:123456@88.182.191.233:8090/stackoverflow/index.html)

I use Google Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 on my computer and it doesn't work on my android phone too.

Edit : it seems that the problem come from the URL. Chrome try to load css with basic authentication in URL and it fail. I've got Provisional headers are shown for the css file.

Do you know why I've got this problem now and how to avoid it ?

Comment: works fine for me. You might have some other issues.

Comment: It seems that on iPhone it work :/ I don't understand why it isn't working on my computer or my phone.

Comment: I edit my question wiith more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found somebody else with this problem :
[Bypass blocking of subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039335/bypass-blocking-of-subresource-requests-whose-urls-contain-embedded-credentials)

Apparently it's a new limitation of chrome :(

Answer (score 0):

When going on your page, I get this warning :

> [Deprecation] Subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials (e.g. `https://user:pass@host/`) are blocked. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856 for more details.

What is happening there, is that you are doing requests to URLs like :
http://stack:123456@88.182.191.233:8090/[...]

So, since you are sending crenditentials il the URL, Chrome blocks it (returning a `(blocked:origin)` status)

Edit: By the way, you should **never** send credentials over URL, especially when you are using http only.

Comment: Thank for your help. How do I tell my page to use standard URL ? I didn't have this problem before.

Comment: You just have to not send the creditentials via URL. use standart URL when doing your queries.